# Image upload works sporadically

Tags: php, image, upload

This is a very open question about a problem that we have.

Basically, we have an image upload function on our site, built on Zend PHP that works great and smoothly almost all the time. Yet the logs show continuously that the entire framework crashes pretty much all the time and the image upload fails and I don't have the slightest idea of what the hell is going on.

The code is working and quite efficient. Server speed is decent. User load is quite average. We have some foreign loaded javascripts that could stall things.

I need some pointers from your vast long history in the field of what it could be.

Comment: Could you post some details on those crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for those of you that spent time trying to help me, but the problem was really complicated and deeply rooted within the system. I tried every possible approach to the problem, but I couldn't reproduce the problem a single time, although the users kept complaining.

Then I finally managed to reproduce the problem. We had not taken account for "jpeg" format (as in opposition to "jpg", giggle giggle, furious programmer). Part of the script shut off without throwing any error at all (despite trycatches) - hence the original problem and unability to provide logs. Another part of the same function continued to throw pointless errors (while in fact successfully upload all images) and can in fact NOT abort the process even if the image IS too grand ("return null" is simply ignored), but that's a different problem all entirely.

Cheers for all that wasted time on all of this, I was really giving up at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to determine is if the problem is reproducible. Will you get the same error again if you try to upload the same image twice?